TS7022 Error setting up Elasticsearch with Mongoosastic
I am trying to setup Elasticsearch using Mongoosastic in my node + expressjs project.
Here's code sample of working model below
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import mongoose, { Schema, Types, Document } from 'mongoose';
import { companyModel } from './Company';
import { MongoosasticDocument, MongoosasticModel } from "mongoosastic";
const mongoosastic = require('mongoosastic')
export interface Contractor extends Document, MongoosasticDocument {
    name: string,
    email: string,
    phone: string,
    address1: string,
    address2: string,
    state: string,
    gstNumber: string,
    panNumber: string,
    companyId: Types.ObjectId; // Reference to another document
}

const contractorSchema = new mongoose.Schema<Contractor>({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    email: {type: String, required: true},
    phone: {type: String, required: true},
    address1: {type: String, required: true},
    address2: {type: String, required: false},
    state: {type: String, required: true},
    gstNumber: {type: String, required: false},
    panNumber: {type: String, required: false},
    companyId: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'Company'} // mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
}, {collection: 'contractors'});

contractorSchema.plugin(mongoosastic, {
    clientOptions: {
      nodes: [
        'http://elasticsearch:9200'  // Use your container's service name as specified in docker-compose.yml
      ]
    }
});

export const ContractorModel = mongoose.model<Contractor, MongoosasticModel<Contractor>>('Contractor', contractorSchema, 'contractors')

Which is working fine, however here's second code sample below which throws an error
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import mongoose, { Document } from 'mongoose';
import { addCustomClaim } from './User';
import { MongoosasticDocument, MongoosasticModel } from "mongoosastic";
const mongoosastic = require('mongoosastic')

export interface Company extends Document, MongoosasticDocument  {
    name: string;
    typeOfIncorporation: string;
    dateOfIncorporation: Date;
    numberOfEmployees: number;
    address1: string;
    address2: string;
    state: string;
    pincode: number;
    email: string;
    phone: string;
    ownerUid: string;
};

const companySchema = new mongoose.Schema<Company>({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    typeOfIncorporation: {type: String, required: true},
    dateOfIncorporation: {type: Date, required: true},
    numberOfEmployees: {type: Number, required: true},
    address1: {type: String, required: true},
    address2: {type: String, required: false},
    state: {type: String, required: true},
    pincode: {type: Number, required: true},
    email: {type: String, required: true},
    phone: {type: String, required: true},
    ownerUid: {type: String, required: true}

}, {collection: 'companies'});

companySchema.plugin(mongoosastic, {
    clientOptions: {
      nodes: [
        'http://elasticsearch:9200'  // Use your container's service name as specified in docker-compose.yml
      ]
    }
});

export const companyModel = mongoose.model<Company, MongoosasticModel<Company>>('Company', companySchema, 'companies');

I get following error on compilation
2024-04-17 14:18:55 /usr/app/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:859
2024-04-17 14:18:55     return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes, diagnostics);
2024-04-17 14:18:55            ^
2024-04-17 14:18:55 TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
2024-04-17 14:18:55 src/models/Company.ts(21,7): error TS7022: 'companySchema' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer.
2024-04-17 14:18:55 src/models/Company.ts(44,14): error TS7022: 'companyModel' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer.

I am not able to find any difference in code yet one file works while other doesn't. can someone explain what's going on here?
Thanks :)
